# How to concatenate string inside html document

Tags: html, angularjs, concatenation

How can I concatenate string in HTML Attribute. I am using angular controller and in the part where I write some array in HTML (Code is below), I want to give input tag name that is "kolicina" + {{idhrana}} witch is attribute of object jelo.

```
 <div class = "rezultat" ng-repeat="jelo in hrana | filter:pretrazi_namirnice">
     <div>  {{jelo.naziv}}  </div>
     <div>  {{jelo.energijaKCal}}</div>
     <div>  {{jelo.proteini}}</div>
     <div>  {{jelo.uglj_hidrati}}</div>
     <div>  {{jelo.masti}}</div>
     <div><input type=text nama="kolicina"+{{idhrana}}></div>
     <div><input  type="button"  ng-click = 'dodaj(jelo)' value="Dodaj"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: @TiepPhan , this is not working

Comment: I solved it i just putted name = 'kolicina{{jelo.idhrana}}'

Answer (score 12):

You can do it like so:

```
<input type=text name="kolicina{{idhrana}}"></div>
```

No need to explicitely concatenate it.
Also, I think you had a typo with `nama` versus the `name`-attribute.

Answer (score 2):

http://plnkr.co/edit/uJcDZkrGNqzSibpgkTc9?p=preview

```
<input type=text name="kolicina {{idhrana}}">
```

working plnkr for understanding. hope this will help you.